# random cron job

Tags: php, cron

I need a script1 that will execute script2 at random times a day.
I'm looking to execute the script2 around 30 times a day within random times.
script1 will be set in the cron job.
Could someone please help how to make it happen?
PS I am not a programmer, so would need something ready to go, please

Comment: Can you elaborate on the purpose? There are probably better solutions....

Comment: This is what I need. I need to run a php script random times a day, around 30 times.

Comment: You want something that *behaves* like it's running randomly 30 times a day. Actually *running it randomly* may not be the best solution. Also, how random exactly does it need to be? 30 times per day at different times? 30 times on average at arbitrary times?

Comment: yes, i want the script2 to run 30 times a day, at random times. script1 should trigger script2. i guess script1 would need to be set in cron at shorter intervals for the possibility of triggering script2.

Answer (score 7):

Seth's solution certainly works, but the number of executions per day will differ. If you want definitely 30 executions, not more and not less, I propose using a cron entry like

```
0 0 * * * gen-executions.sh
```

and a script `gen-executions.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for number in $(seq 30)
do
    hour=$(( ${RANDOM}*24/32768 ))
    minute=$(( ${RANDOM}*60/32768 ))
    at -f /path/to/script.sh $(printf "%02d" ${hour}):$(printf "%02d" ${minute})
done
```

This generates exactly 30 executions of `/path/to/script.sh` at random times of the day using at.

Answer (score 2):

```
* * * * * script1.sh

#!/bin/bash
if [ $(($RANDOM*100/32768)) -gt 2 ]; then exit; fi
exec php script2.php
```

Comment: so, should i save the part beginning #!/bin/bash as a script1.sh? also, how do i adjust the time randomness? what is 32768? forgive the noob.

Comment: @Henry: $RANDOM generates a random number between 0 and 32767.  30[executions/day]/(60*24)[minutes/day] == .02 [executions per minute] or 2% chance of executing once a minute.  Yes, save the lines starting with #!/bin/bash to a file name script1.sh and put the lines above in your crontab.

Comment: Seth, in your answer it says 32768 and in comment 32767, which one is it? I get how you get the percentage chance, but i still don't understand why you chose 32768? why not 30000?

Comment: @Henry: There are 32768 numbers between 0 and 32767 (inclusive).  The percentage chance is the bit about 30/(60*24) I mentioned before.  I use 32768 because that is what $RANDOM gives me.  If it generated numbers between 0 and 29999, I would have 30000, but it does not.