# How do I schedule the Let's Encrypt certbot to automatically renew my certificate in cron?

Tags: cron, lets-encrypt, certbot

I've seen conflicting recommendations. From the [eff.org docs](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-apache):

> if you're setting up a cron or systemd job, we recommend running it twice per day... Please select a random minute within the hour for your renewal tasks.

I've also seen recommendations for [weekly jobs](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2016/04/how-to-install-lets-encrypt-certificates-on-ubuntu-server-with-apache2/).

I'm not a cron expert, so I'd prefer an answer with detailed steps for setting up the cron job.

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault and [has been asked there](https://serverfault.com/questions/790772/cron-job-for-lets-encrypt-renewal).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I recently (April 2018) installed and ran certbot (version 0.22.2) on an Ubuntu 16.04 server, and a renewal cron job was created automatically in /etc/cron.d/certbot.

Here's the cron job that was created:

```
# /etc/cron.d/certbot: crontab entries for the certbot package
#
# Upstream recommends attempting renewal twice a day
#
# Eventually, this will be an opportunity to validate certificates
# haven't been revoked, etc.  Renewal will only occur if expiration
# is within 30 days.
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew
```

Please check this before putting a new Cron job.

**Update (From @Hamish Downer's comment):**

It's worth being aware that the above cron job won't run certbot renew **if /run/systemd/system is present** - this is because instead a systemd timer is running certbot - [read more about certbot and systemd timers here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/cerbot-cron-job/23895/5).

Comment: Very relevant answer. The `certbot renew` command (available as of certbot 0.10.0) solves a lot of the older `certbot-auto` hastles. See [Certbot docs](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewing-certificates) for more information.

Comment: As of June 2019 certbot v0.31.0 it's now `rand(43200)` instead of 3600. I guess they want to spread the requests over the entire 12-hour period, and not just the first hour.

Comment: Switched this to the accepted answer as it seems simpler and more current.

Comment: I need help as I am fairly new to cron... I running Ubuntu 18.04 and after successfully getting the cert. Running `crontab -l` or `sudo crontab -l` shows "no crontab for <user>`. Is this supposed to happen? How do I know if the referenced cronjob above will run? How does one check it?

Comment: I hope you edit the answer and add @HamishDowner comment. It clarified a very important point.

Answer (score 40):

So I settled on scheduling it to run once a day. First I tested auto-renew as [the docs recommend](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-apache):

```
sudo letsencrypt renew --dry-run --agree-tos
```

Then I updated the crontab:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This is the line I added:

```
12 3 * * *   letsencrypt renew >> /var/log/letsencrypt/renew.log
```

This runs the renew everday at 3:12 am. I presume the docs recommend "a random minute within the hour" to distribute the load on the renew servers. So I suppose anything other than 0, 15, 30, or 45 is preferred.

I looked into [randomizing the minute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9049460/1093087) in the cron setting, like Jenkins allows you to do.
On original EEF page is this Example:

```bash
0 0,12 * * * python -c 'import random; import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)' && /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto renew
```

Finally, I tested the cron command using [sudo bash](https://askubuntu.com/a/230482/46766):

```bash
sudo bash -c "letsencrypt renew >> /var/log/letsencrypt/renew.log"
```

Comment: Consider upgrading to `certbot` so that you can automatically reload the web server when the certificate renewal succeeds. i.e. `certbot renew --renew-hook 'service nginx reload'`.

Comment: To avoid service overload, please add a random sleep in between (`perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))'`). Or better use the systemd certbot timer & service, which is now a days automatically deployed when installing the certbot package. See my post up.

Comment: There is an automated way, don't use crontab. See my answer below.

Answer (score 38):

In Debian Jessie and up (incl. Ubuntu) cron is not executed for Certbot renewal. Instead the systemd timer is used.

**UPDATE:** When you're using **Snap** (which is the recommended install method of Certbot). Off the record: I don't like Snap.

Auto renew timer is located at: `/etc/systemd/system/snap.certbot.renew.timer`. Which has the content:

```
[Unit]
# Auto-generated, DO NOT EDIT
Description=Timer renew for snap application certbot.renew
Requires=snap-certbot-3566.mount
After=snap-certbot-3566.mount
X-Snappy=yes

[Timer]
Unit=snap.certbot.renew.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* 08:41
OnCalendar=*-*-* 14:01

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

As you can see the renew job service is called twice a day. Once [ACME ARI extension](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-acme-ari/) is implemented this renew frequency might need to be increased in the future, but I digress.

*Note:* Do **not** try to modify these files, changes will be reverted back by a snap refresh.

And the service file `/etc/systemd/system/snap.certbot.renew.service`, that the timer is triggering, has the following content:

```
[Unit]
# Auto-generated, DO NOT EDIT
Description=Service for snap application certbot.renew
Requires=snap-certbot-3566.mount
Wants=network.target
After=snap-certbot-3566.mount network.target snapd.apparmor.service
X-Snappy=yes

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/environment
ExecStart=/usr/bin/snap run --timer="00:00~24:00/2" certbot.renew
SyslogIdentifier=certbot.renew
Restart=no
WorkingDirectory=/var/snap/certbot/3566
TimeoutStopSec=30
Type=oneshot
```

See the status of the timer: `systemctl status snap.certbot.renew.timer`

When using the Nginx installer via certbot (`certbot --nginx`), the renew configuration files are located in the `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal` directory. These Certbot conf files contain information that the certificate(s) are deployed to the Nginx server and reload Nginx automatically when required:

```
authenticator = nginx
installer = nginx
server = https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
key_type = ecdsa
```

---

On distros that might not have Snap (good!), the timer should be  located at: `/lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer`. With the service: `/lib/systemd/system/certbot.service`

Which contains:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/certbot -q renew
PrivateTmp=true
```

In order to list all the timers, execute the following command in the terminal:

`systemctl list-timers`

Hopefully Certbot is part of this:

> Mon 2019-02-04 08:38:45 CET  9h left       Sun 2019-02-03 15:25:41 CET
> 8h ago       certbot.timer                certbot.service

How-to install Certbot on a older Debian based distro (it may vary depending on your Linux distribution).

But within Debian Stretch for example you can install the back-port package of `certbot` via:

`sudo apt-get install certbot -t stretch-backports`

This will install the files I showed above for you automatically! And thus automatically schedule a certbot timer for you, which runs the service, which runs again the renew.

Manually running a renew is always possible via:

`sudo /usr/bin/certbot renew`

Can be forced via `--force-renewal` flag. For more info see the help text of renew:

`/usr/bin/certbot --help renew`

Files part of the certbot package (incl. but not limited by):

```
dpkg-query -L certbot
...
/lib/systemd/system/certbot.service
/lib/systemd/system/certbot.timer
...
```

Comment: If you are a Raspberry PI user *this* is the way to go, do not mess with crontab.

Comment: This post deserves a lot more credit than it's getting. For the large number of people using Debian, Ubuntu et al, it's kind of a big deal that you don't need to set up your own cron and 'it just renews'.

Comment: I have  an issue where we are fronting a java application and because of internal reasons cannot put the  certs in java, so they have to be in apache. The problem is the webtree is not visible so we do --standalone and have apache2 present the certificates (this has the benefit of not caring what's behind the webserver), but because of the way certbot works we have to kill the webserver and restart it.  We cannot depend on the systemd process so we have to use cron and we kill apache2 and run certbot and restart apache2 and we do it once every 3 weeks and forcibly renew the certificate.

Comment: @TekOps I wish there was a better way for Apache2.

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg  I made sure systemd wasn't running it in the background because of my setup that would not work so  I set up a cron job (/usr/bin/certbot renew --force-renewal --standalone -n 2>&1) to run twice a month  in the evening.   It  stops apache and restarts it around this  fetch  and it is working great!

Answer (score 8):

Ok. So being on Debian (or Ubuntu) with systemd I had probably the same problem like others - cron job not firing. I needed to make some extra steps and observations not mentioned elsewhere, so making separate answer for it.

---

In my case the `/etc/systemd/system/` directory exists, so the job in `/etc/cron.d/certbot` stops at the initial test.

**BUT** the `/etc/systemd/system/certbot.timer` was a pointer to `/dev/null`. That means it is a *masked* timer. When I did `systemd unmask certbot.timer` the link was removed, but I had nothing to replace it with (tried `locate certbot.timer` but none was installed on my system). I could also still see the timer in `systemd list-timers --all`, but it was an emtpy file so removed that too using `systemd disable certbot.timer`. The service in `/etc/systemd/system/certbot.service` was completely **absent**.

So after actually cleaning all the certbot-related stuff from `/etc/systemd/system/` I **created the necessary files manually**.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/certbot-renewal.service
[Unit]
Description=Certbot Renewal
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/certbot -q renew --post-hook "systemctl reload nginx"
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/certbot-renewal.timer
[Unit]
Description=Run certbot twice daily

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00,12:00:00
RandomizedDelaySec=43200
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

The timer file content comes from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479467/137818).

I started and checked the whole thing by running:

```
sudo systemctl start certbot-renewal.timer
sudo systemctl enable certbot-renewal.timer
sudo systemctl list-timers --all
sudo journalctl -u certbot-renewal.service
```

Few more notes:

- I have certbot in `/usr/local/bin/certbot` instead of `/usr/bin/certbot` (figured using `which certbot`), don't know why.
- I'm using nginx, so need to reload it in the post-hook to take the renewed certs into account.

Comment: This doesn't work on my machine. :/

Comment: When you installed certbot on Debian via snap you should have preinstalled renew timer & service via systemd timer. Eg see: `systemctl status snap.certbot.renew.timer`. See my reply above for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following line to `/etc/crontab` runs renewal attempt **daily** on a random minute between **00:00** and approximately **16:40**:

```
1  1    * * *   root    sleep ${RANDOM:0:3}m && /home/admin/certbot-auto renew --quiet --no-self-upgrade --authenticator webroot --installer apache -w /var/www/mywebroot
```

Works great for more than a year now.

The renew command itself may vary for you - I used webroot as it seemed most robust at that time.

Answer (score 2):

Normally while you run a certbot for any webserver in an Ubuntu 16.04 server it automatically creates a cron

```
#cat /etc/cron.d/certbot

0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(3600))' && certbot -q renew
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers worked for me in 2023, because certbot cannot renew if nginx is running on port 80.

The following entry in the crontab works:

`43 6 * * * sudo certbot renew --pre-hook "sudo systemctl stop nginx" --post-hook "sudo systemctl start nginx"`

Comment: This is not nginx-specific; Apache would have the same issue. And there is a better way. Look at the --webroot option. The underlying issue is that one of the authentication mechanisms certbot uses is to place a particular file in the Web server's root. Certbot can use its own Web server for the purpose (but that is disruptive and requires stopping the "normal" Web server), or it can place the file into the root of the normal Web server, and leave that untouched. You are using the first method. Switch to the second one to keep your server running.

Answer (score 0):

for renew every 2 month:

```
#nano /etc/cron.d/certbot    

30 03 01 */2 * echo "2" | certbot --nginx -v -d yourdomain.com
```

Comment: Be careful with that approach. If the cert is valid for, say, three months, then it wouldn't get renewed after two months (because it's too early), and would expire before the next certbot run in four months. You should always run certbot at least once per week or so to avoid this isssue.

Comment: Certbot already deploys a renew systemd timer (with snap or without snap installation), setting up a manual cronjob is not required. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured  out  how to make it run by cron on systems where the webserver could not be stopped/started by the certbot tool reliably or could not access the verification file because  it  is not in the webtree.  In this case you  do the initial setup of an offline initial installation and then renewals can be done by cron.

Here is my script and it is working in production:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# get root apache process id
pid=`ps -ef |grep apache2 |grep root | egrep -v "grep" |awk '{print $2;}'`

echo "Found  Apache2  pid=($pid)\n"

# shut it down gracefully (our way)

# request shutdown
kill -TERM $pid

# wait 4 seconds
sleep 4

# no running .pid to remove

# show if it is still in memory
ps -ef |grep apache2 |egrep -v "grep"

# now get new  certificate
# request just certificate,  with this hostname, standalone server, non-interactive
# uncomment for real certificates, but make sure test certificate is  commented
#/usr/bin/certbot certonly --test-cert --standalone -n -d <your.server.tld> 2>&1
# uncomment for test certificates
#/usr/bin/certbot certonly --test-cert --dry-run --standalone -n -d <your.server.tld> 2>&1
/usr/bin/certbot renew --force-renewal --standalone -n 2>&1

# restart apache2 (we know it will report fail, but it will actually start it)
echo "starting apache2...\n"
/bin/systemctl start apache2 2>&1

# check if it's in memory...
npid=`ps -ef |grep apache2 |grep root | egrep -v "grep" |awk '{print $2;}'`

echo "Found New Apache2  pid=($npid)\n"

# if npid is empty try restarting again...
#/bin/systemctl restart apache2 2>&1

echo "done."
echo ""
```

---

I set up the cronjob as follows:

---

```
# stop apache2, forcibly renew every 3 weeks and then restart apache2
0 1 3,18 * *    /bin/touch /var/adm/ratglc_ssl_certbot.log; /home/tk/bin/ratglc 2>&1 >> /var/adm/ratglc_ssl_certbot.log
```

---

I do have other monitoring that alerts me if SSL stops working or the webserver does  not come back online and so far neither of those things has happened.  One thing-- systemctl reports apache2 "did not start" but it did and this script checks that.  I write all output to a log for review/monitoring later.

It's  not  pretty but it works.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score -1):

To keep simple set a timer to validate automatically:

```
systemctl status certbot.timer
```

Comment: Use: `systemctl status snap.certbot.renew.timer` when Certbot is installed via Snap. But this response above doesn't really answer the question. See my answer above for much more info and details.