# How to setup CRON job to run every 10 minutes exactly from 9:24:59 to 15:14:59?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, cron-task

I need to setup 2 cron jobs with very precise timing for my PHP code.

**Cron 1:**

Run cron job every 10 minutes, every day between 9:24:59 to 15:14:59.
i.e cron job starting from every morning 9 hours 24 minutes 59 seconds to afternoon 15 hours 14 minutes 59 seconds. The cron should run every 10 minutes, 
example:

```
9:24:59
9:34:59
9:44:59
9:54:59
...
14:54:59
15:04:59
15:14:59
```

**Cron 2:**

Run cron job every 10 minutes, every day between 9:15 to 15:05.
For example:

```
9:15
9:25
9:35
9:45
...
14:45
14:55
15:05
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/411406/set-a-cron-every-certain-hours-between-certain-hours

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can configure a cronjob close to your needs with the right syntax, but if you need it on the second scale, you're out of luck with cron. You'll probably need to just have a background script running all the time for that (or let the script sleep first when you call it early) or some cron tool. A tool you'll probably gonna love for configuring cron times: [https://crontab.guru/](https://crontab.guru/#*/10_9-15_*_*_*)

Comment: What's with the bizarre timing requirements?

Comment: @Sammitch I am trying  to construct 10 minutes candlesticks for NSE stocks. Usually candlesticks are constructed with (OHLC) Open, High, Low, Close prices of the stocks,  but as per my requirement I don't have to construct candlesticks with upper shadow & lower shadow, so I have planned to neglect High & low price of the stocks at a specific time period. I have just planned to construct candlesticks with Open & Close prices of the stocks. Instead of listening and recording every tick by tick data of stocks through websocket,...

Comment: @Sammitch I will just record last traded price of stocks at a specific time to construct candlesticks.  For example,  I will record last traded price of the stocks at 9:15 as Open price of the first 10 minutes candlesticks and last traded price at 9:24:59 as Close price of the first 10 minutes candlesticks. Similarly for every 10 minutes. First candlestick: open price - 9:15 ; close price - 9:24:59 ; Second candlestick: open price - 9:25 ; close price - 9:34:59 ;

Comment: Ok well trying to implement this with cron is going to be a _real bad time_, even if you could just run every 10 minutes on the tens. You're going to want to write a daemon for this as a start, and how you scale out from there is a whole other conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the time range for the script in the crontab file using bash syntax. For example see: [Cron jobs and random times, within given hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049460/cron-jobs-and-random-times-within-given-hours/16289693#16289693) and [How to check if the current time is between 23:00 and 06:30](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395933/how-to-check-if-the-current-time-is-between-2300-and-0630).

Using bash commands in a single line can be difficult to understand and maintain. A simpler option is to use 3 cron tab entries. The first entry will run the script every 10 min from 09:25 to to 09:55. The second entry will run the script every 10 min from 10:05 to 14:55. The third entry will run the script from 15:05 to 15:15. These three crontab entries will cause the script to run at 09:25, 09:35, 09:45 .... 15:15. Following are the three crontab entries:

```
25-55/10 9 * * * script-path
5-55/10 10-14 * * * script-path
5-15/10 15 * * * script-path
```

You should confirm that the script runs at the correct times

Comment: I don't have shell script privilege with the server since I am using shared hosting server, I cannot initiate the cron job exactly at 9:24:59 from my php code. I have to create the cron job through the cpanel's cron job editor and run the desired php file.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Syntax for my cron tab editor is a bit different but figured that out and every thing works fine. I really appreciate your help. As per my Cron editor, Cron 1 syntax: 15,25,35,45,55 9 * * * script-path and 5,15,25,35,45,55 10,11,12,13,14 * * * script-path and 5 15 * * * script-path. For Cron 2 syntax: 24,34,44,54 9 * * * sleep 59; script-path and 4,14,24,34,44,54 10,11,12,13,14 * * *   sleep 59; script-path and 4,14 15 * * * sleep 59; script-path.

Answer (score 0):

To make it run any process every 10 minutes just add:

*/10 * *  *  *

I would make my limitations of time from my PHP function.

[image: Crontabs explanation]

[Source](https://crontab.guru/every-10-minutes)

Comment: You can also set the hour range using `-`: `*/10 9-15 * * *`

Comment: @user3116428 I don't have shell script privilege with the server since I am using shared hosting server, I cannot initiate the cron job exactly at 9:24:59 from my php code. I have to create the cron job through the cpanel's cron job editor and run the desired php file.