# Running Python schedule daily at random times

Tags: python, scheduler

How do I run a scheduled job at random times daily starting with today? I want to use the `schedule` package.

`pip install schedule`

```
import schedule

def job()
   print("foo")
   return schedule.CancelJob

while True:
   time_str = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(random.randint(6, 10), random.randint(0, 59))
   print("Scheduled for {}".format(time_str))
   schedule.every().day.at(time_str).do(job)
   schedule.run_pending()
```

The above code just spins:

```
Scheduled for 06:36
Scheduled for 10:00
Scheduled for 06:18
```

Comment: You could maybe use [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049460/cron-jobs-and-random-times-within-given-hours) if you're on a unix os and set random times through there?

Comment: Needs to run on both Windows and Linux and I'd prefer all the logic to be in one package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're providing a moving target by putting your random time generator inside you while loop. Specifically, after reviewing the source code [here](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/schedule.html), it is clear that the job will only run if `datetime.datetime.now() >= self.next_run` is true (see `scheduler.run_pending()` and `job.should_run()` definitions). Because you are always moving `job.next_run`, you will only hit it if it happens to be in the past on that particular iteration of the loop. Interestingly, I think this would cause a bug where the probability of actually running your job increases as you approach 24:00, though this has yet to be shown. I think you need to create a separate function for generating the next random time, and call it from your job function. For example:

```
import schedule
import time
import random

def job():
   print("foo")
   schedule_next_run()
   return schedule.CancelJob

def schedule_next_run():
   time_str = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(random.randint(6, 10), random.randint(0, 59))
   schedule.clear()
   print("Scheduled for {}".format(time_str))
   schedule.every().day.at(time_str).do(job)

schedule_next_run()

while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(60)
```

Note that the example may not be random for the day that the job starts, as your random time may be before the time you happen to start your script. You could work in a way to pick a random time in the future on the first day to circumvent this as needed.

To verify the above example, I used shorter time spans. The following works for me:

```
import schedule
import time
import random

def job():
   print("foo")
   schedule_next_run()
   return schedule.CancelJob

def schedule_next_run():
   time_span = random.randint(1, 5)
   schedule.clear()
   print(f'Scheduled in {time_span} seconds')
   schedule.every(time_span).seconds.do(job)

schedule_next_run()

while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
```

Comment: What do you mean "spins"? The while loop is infinite and `schedule.run_pending()` does not hold execution. Constant iteration of the while loop is expected. It is essentially checking whether present time is greater than or equal to the last scheduled job every iteration.

Comment: To truly check the script, you have to wait for your job to run. For this reason, you may want to practice with shorter time spans. Also, you may want to put a `time.sleep` statement in your while loop that is on the order of job frequency to minimize overhead.