# How to run cron job at a random time in node js?

Tags: node.js, cron

There are many questions related to my question but none that I could find are for node js such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049460/cron-jobs-and-random-times-within-given-hours), in addition, I would like to know how to run a cron job at a random time within a period every period, for my particular use I would like to run a cron job at a random time within an hour every hour. For example the random time between 10:00-11:00 is 10:15 then the random time between 11:00-12:00 is 11:53, and so on.

Comment: Set your cron to 10:00 ans add random timeout. It's what is done in the answers to the question you linked

Comment: I've solved this but getting random delay(between the minimum(0) and maximum time(60*60 = 3600)) in the cron job's callback and sleeping for that random amount of seconds before proceeding with the callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
function scraper() {
  // do something here
}

// CronJob runs function every hour at minute 0 second 0
const scraperTimer = new CronJob('0 0 */1 * * *', function () {
  // set random delay between 5(min) and 50(max) minutes
  const delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3e6 - 300000) +   300000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    scraper();
  }, delay);

  console.log(`running scraper in ${delay / 60000} minutes`);
});

scraperTimer.Start()
```

It would be good to be cautious of scope when using Cron and timers, memory leaks can happen.