# How to make a cron job with random offset

Tags: unix, cron

I have many services that need perform a sync job every 10 minutes, since these containers are using a shared resource it is not desirable, that they all do the syncing at the same time. I want to solve it with a cron job and I want to be sure that there are not more than 10 minutes between a sync and that when the container spins up a sync is performed within the first 10 minutes.

So a potential solution would be, something like "sleep a 0-10 minutes, start process every 10 minutes with first interaction starting now"

But if in run "*/10 * * * *" the first execution first happens after 10 minutes. What am I doing wrong and do you have an idea for another implementation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cron jobs and random times, within given hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049460/cron-jobs-and-random-times-within-given-hours)

Comment: No it does not. As i read it all the solution proposed in that question, the first run starts 10 minutes + random time which based on the requirements is not a valid solution.

Comment: I see .. well there is also a nice read on here (https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2020/06/randomly-spacing-cron-jobs/), which does show options using cronie, but main idea stays the same, about random sleep just before job executes tho ..

Comment: Are you sure you want them random? With a random offset, different containers might sync at the same time. When you prefer a method where the sync time is evenly sliced between the different jobs, can you tell us how many jobs you might have and how long the sync time is.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use your proposed crontab entry and have each invocation perform a deterministic sleep based on a unique ID assigned to each container. Simply compute the modulo of that ID so you get a value within a ten minute range. A more sophisticated solution is a global mutex that each sync job has to acquire before proceeding.

Comment: The ideal solution imho is to use a service instead of cron - each of those services depends on a service that sleeps randomly up to 10m, syncs, and back again; if you insist on using cron, schedule every 5 minutes + random(less than 5m) I guess.